# Image is not downloading?

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm learning to download images, by managing bitmaps. I used `BitmapFactory:options.inJustDecodeBounds` to download images.When i use this statement, 
`Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in)` -it works.
But when i used sample size and tried to calculate, its not downloading. i used something like this:

```
public Bitmap downloadUrlToStream(String urlString, final ImageView imageView) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedInputStream in = null;

        try {
            final URL url = new URL(urlString);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream(), IO_BUFFER_SIZE);

            return decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(200,200,in);

        } catch (final IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in downloadBitmap - " + e);
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (in != null) {
                    in.close();
                }
            } catch (final IOException e) {
            }
        }
        return null;    }

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(int reqWidth, int reqHeight, InputStream is) {

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // BEGIN_INCLUDE (calculate_sample_size)
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and
            // keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }

            // This offers some additional logic in case the image has a strange
            // aspect ratio. For example, a panorama may have a much larger
            // width than height. In these cases the total pixels might still
            // end up being too large to fit comfortably in memory, so we should
            // be more aggressive with sample down the image (=larger
            // inSampleSize).

            long totalPixels = width * height / inSampleSize;

            // Anything more than 2x the requested pixels we'll sample down
            // further
            final long totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;

            while (totalPixels > totalReqPixelsCap) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
                totalPixels /= 2;
            }
        }
        return inSampleSize;
        // END_INCLUDE (calculate_sample_size)
}
```

Is there a problem with calculateSamplesize() method. Y its not working?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you a different way that works like a charm: Android Query.

You can download that jar file from here: http://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/list

```
AQuery androidAQuery=new AQuery(this);
```

As an example:

```
androidAQuery.id(YOUR IMAGEVIEW).image(YOUR IMAGE TO LOAD, true, true, getDeviceWidth(), ANY DEFAULT IMAGE YOU WANT TO SHOW);
```

Using above code you can directly show your Image through url. Now below code is to get Bitmap Directly from the url:

```
   androidAQuery.ajax(YOUR IMAGE URL,Bitmap.class,0,new AjaxCallback<Bitmap>(){
                            @Override
                            public void callback(String url, Bitmap object, AjaxStatus status) {
                                super.callback(url, object, status);

                                //You will get Bitmap from object.
                            }


  });
```

This library is provided by Android itself, so use it and see the result whatever you want.

It's very fast and accurate, and using this you can find many more features like Animation when loading, getting a bitmap, if needed, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to use it. But I'm a beginner and I want to know, why this is not working. I might have missed something

Comment: Never use this, forget this for images dear, its bad way to download image.

Comment: Thank you. But I'm told to do it, by using this technique only..That's y i wanted to know the problem

Comment: What response or are you getting?

Comment: The problem is that i used options twice, while calculating sample size..and i think because of that it's not working

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for it not to work. Make sure your `calculateInSampleSize` works properly.

`options.inSampleSize` need to be higher than 1. Make sure you are getting a valid value here.

Comment: The problem is that i used options twice, while calculating sample size..and i think because of that it's not working.. Ill update my question with sample size method

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
public void DownloadImageFromPath(String path){
            InputStream in =null;
            Bitmap bmp=null;
             ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
             int responseCode = -1;
            try{

                 URL url = new URL(path);//"http://192.xx.xx.xx/mypath/img1.jpg
                 HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                 con.setDoInput(true);
                 con.connect();
                 responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                 if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                 {
                     //download 
                     in = con.getInputStream();
                     bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                     in.close();
                     iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                 }

            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                Log.e("Exception",ex.toString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the downloaded file in bitmap and set the bitmap in imageView

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I want to sample down its size, to avoid out of memory exception

Comment: int widthPx = 150;  //you can set width
    int heightPx = 150; //you can set height
    bmp=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, widthPx, heightPx, true);